# Angular : error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api

I am a beginner in Angular, and I encounter a strange error, it sais that it didn't find the property data in the API object I am trying to get data from a simple API, and display it in my page here is the code.

```
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
 users: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data=>{
      this.users=data;
      console.log(this.users);

    });
  }


}
```

The Template is like so

```
<ul *ngIf="users">
  <li *ngFor="let user of users.data">
    <img [src]="user.avatar">
     <p>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have been stock here for hours. When I console log, there is a data property and has all the information of the users, that is what I am trying to display, it shows me that   does not exist. and here is the API link :  https://reqres.in/api/users
Please help.

And the function in the service class is :

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers(){
       return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  }
}
```

Comment: `ngIf` syntax appears to be wrong.

Comment: Your code works fine. make sure you have correctly written `ngIf`.

Comment: yeh, I fixed it and still, it doesn't recognize users.data .

Comment: I copied your code it works fine.

Comment: core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. in the consoles  @Mridul

Comment: Issue is with your `*ngIf`. Try writing like this: `<ul *ngIf="users !== undefined">`.

Comment: I tried with different APIs of users, the same problem, the console shows me, vendor.js:sourcemap:15103 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Can you add the function of service class?

Comment: Are there any other api class on the same page? maybe error is due to some other. this works fine.

Comment: Okay, thanks, yes there is another call of another API in another component, will that affect it? its in another service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and its worked fine.still you get error you can define like users?.data in ngFor loop.

Comment: Something must be going in on with my chrome navigator then, I couldn't fix it, I tried other APIs, with an Array integrated inside the object, nothing it can not access it! any suggestion? please

Comment: Try to clear site data from Applicaton tab from developer console and do hard refresh.

Comment: I don't understand, why it cannot access the data inside the array inside the object !?  When its a simple API object it works fine, but when it comes to this kinds, cant load them @

Comment: The server was frozen, i just had to hard refresh it and then reopen it, and it worked Thank you, guys.